# Pop-up Slider in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, popup, slider, carousel

I have created a pop-up form using Popup maker and Metaslider plugin to allow the user to slide between two different images.

I need to only display the contact form for image 1, and for image 2 i wish to replace the contact form with text.

Code inside popupmaker editor:

```html
<div style="width:700px; height:490px;"> [metaslider id="716"]</div>

&nbsp;
<p style="text-align: center;">[contact-form-7 id="728" 
title="Untitled"]</p>
```

I tried to use the id of the contact form to hide the image inside the metaslider editor in image 2 using:

```html
.728 {
    display: none;
    }
```

Unsuccessful. How can I change the CSS below to hide the contact form shortcode for image 1 only?

Comment: You can't target a contactform7 by its ID '728' it is only used to find wich form to display. We need the rendered code to help you.

Comment: I might be out of my depth here, but here goes:
<div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f728-o2" lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: So to hide your form you should use #wpcf7-f728-o2 {display: none;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't target a contactform7 by its ID '728' it is only used to find wich form to display.

As described in your comment, the shortcode displays:

```
<div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f728-o2" lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
```

So to hide this particular form with CSS, you need to target its ID on front as follow:

```
#wpcf7-f728-o2 {
   display: none;
}
```